Help With Wiring a 4-Way Switch
I have searched about 4-Way switches and how to wire them but the "standard" set up that I find on almost all of the diagrams does not match how mine is set up and I found another diagram that was much more similar to mine(though not exact) and someone commented that it is not legal to wire it that way in the US(They said it had a switching Neutral).
So I'm posting to:
A) Figure out how to wire it(I took pictures before removing the switches which, have of course, gone missing).
and
B) Find out if the way the previous owner did it is not legal and if I need to do it differently.
So the set up is in a basement there is a 3 Way switch at the top of the stairs, 4-Way switch at the bottom of the stairs, and a 3-Way switch at a rear entrance to the basement. Power/Line is supplied at the 3-way switch at the rear door to the basement and the light/Load wires are at the 4-Way switch.(Diagram below)
Thank you


Your diagram is ignoring how power is wired to the right-hand switch. This is important. Please give us actual photographs of the current wiring.

Sorry! I did not include that on the diagram but should have!

The notations "NO" and "NC" are unusual, and somewhat misleading, on a 3-way switch, inasmuch as there is no "normal" position on such switches.

In the interest of keeping everything the same in your diagram, I finished it like this. The 4-way switch alternates between "cross" and "straight" connections, so it gets both travelers.

Note that on the right side, your power-in cable should have "hot" black and "neutral" blue; the 14/3 cable coming out toward the large central "junction box" if that's what is, should use the black as one of the travelers so the blue can remain "neutral". Travelers should both be marked as such at the switches, typically with yellow tape.
Adjusting wire color to the typical, it should look like this instead:


Thank you for the response!
I have set everything up as you put in the diagram(at least i'm almost positive I have)
The 4 way switch and the back door switch where power originates from both work and turn on and off the light. The switch at the top of the stairs does not do anything in either position.
It is possible that the wire from the top of the stairs is not direct to the switch although it really seems like it is, there is a short area where it goes up into the ceiling and in the wall to the switch where i do not have viability.
If there is any other information needed

I will say, it's pretty unusual for the light to be in the middle like this. Typical 3-way configurations will have the light cable coming from the switch on one end. If you can post pictures of the wiring at each switch, junction box, and the light, we might be able to tell you more.
